# span two rows in flexbox

Tags: css, flexbox

I'm trying to achieve the following layout with flexbox so that the left column spans two rows. IS this possible?

Thanks!

[image]

Comment: It is possible, but where's the code you've tried?

Answer (score 0):

hmm simple but will do the trick, you just have to use multiple flex containers, and one of them will have a flex-direction: column ...

```
<style type="text/css">
    .main {}
    .flex {display: flex;}
    .flex-3 {flex-grow: 3}
    .flex-1 {flex-grow: 1}
    .big-image {width: 100%;height: 400px;}
    .small-image {width: 100%;height: 200px;}
    .flex.column {flex-direction: column;}
    body img {width: 85%;display: block; margin: auto;background-color: white;}

</style>

<div class="main">

    <div class="flex">
        <div class="flex-3"><img class="big-image"></div>

        <div class="flex flex-1 column" >
               <div class="flex-1"><img class="small-image"></div>
               <div class="flex-1"><img class="small-image"></div>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: thanks but can I not do it without setting height so that it is fluid?

Comment: you can calculate height with css by calc